# Python 3x/Tkinter, resize column width

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is part of my code, I'm trying to resize column 22.                                                                             For when there is no text, that empty space does not appear.

I tried to use the options columnconfigure, grid_fogert, grid_remove, as you can see, but must be doing something wrong, as they are not working.

Any help?

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.geometry("1300x775")

CoeSegur = Entry(janela, width=10, font=("Calibri", "12"))
CoeSegur.insert(END, 2)
CoeSegur.grid(row=10, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E)

CoeTracao = Entry(janela, width=10, font=("Calibri", "12"))
CoeTracao.insert(END, 0)
CoeTracao.grid(row=11, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E)

def btcal_click():

    cleartext = (Label(janela, width=0, text=()))
    cleartext.grid(row=1, rowspan=33, column=13, columnspan=23, sticky=N + S + W + E)

    janela.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
    Grid.columnconfigure(janela, 0, weight=0)

    test = (Label(janela, width=0))
    test.grid(row=3, column=22)
    test.grid_forget()
    test.grid_remove()

    cSeg = float(CoeSegur.get())
    cSegT = float(CoeTracao.get())


    if cSeg > 0 and cSegT > 0:
        rta = (Label(janela, text="C. (ton.)", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"), width=9)).grid(row=3, column=21)
        rtta = (Label(janela, text="T. (ton.)", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"), width=9)).grid(row=3, column=22)
    else:
        if cSeg == 0:
            rtta = (Label(janela, text="T. (ton.)", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"), width=9)).grid(row=3, column=21)
        else:
            rta = (Label(janela, text="C. (ton.)", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"), width=9)).grid(row=3, column=21)

    if cSeg > 0 and cSegT > 0:
        rta = (Label(janela, text="C. (ton.)", bg="lightgrey", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"),
                     width=9)).grid(row=3, column=24)
        rtta = (Label(janela, text="T. (ton.)", bg="lightgrey", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"),
                      width=9)).grid(row=3, column=25)
    else:
        if cSeg == 0:
            rtta = (
            Label(janela, text="T. (ton.)", bg="lightgrey", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"),
                  width=9)).grid(row=3, column=24)
        else:
            rta = (
            Label(janela, text="C. (ton.)", bg="lightgrey", relief=GROOVE, font=("Calibri", "12"),
                  width=9)).grid(row=3, column=24)

btcal = (Button(janela, width=10, height=1, text="CALCULAR", font=("Calibri", "11"), bg="lightgrey", command=btcal_click)).grid(row=20, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=W + E, padx=5)

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code unrelated to the problem. Can you please reduce your code down to a [mcve],?

Comment: Columns and rows that have nothing in them have a size of zero. Why are you trying to configure column 22? And if you want column 22 to have a size, why are you configuring it to have a minsize of zero?

Comment: Why in entry1 = 2 and entry2 = 3, column 22 has value text and width = 9 . But in the situation entry1 = 2 and entry2 = 0 no. But the column retains the width = 9. Reduced code